# Network, battery, and sound icons missing from notifications in vista

Tags: windows-vista, icons, notification-area

The irritating thing is that I know I answered this question once, and now I can't find my own answer --

The network, battery, and sound icons are missing from the notification area and the boxes to enable them are grayed out in Taskbar Properties.  How to I un-gray them?

**Update:**  As it turned out, the problem cleared up after rebooting again.  Dunno what the basic cause was, but I vaguely recall from last time that manually restarting some service fixed it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Have you tried checking here? Launch local policy editor and check under - User Configuration, Administrative Templates, and Start Menu and Taskbar.

Comment: @BobbyAlexander - Except what is "local policy editor"?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander - Taskbar properties, Notification Area tab, the three boxes below "clock" are gray.

Comment: Which edition of Vista do you have?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander Home Premium service pack 2

Comment: @BobbyAlexander -- "Taskbar and Start Menu" is an option in Control Panel and is the same menu one gets with the taskbar "properties" option (with the same 3 gray options).

Comment: (But it was some mysterious option like that that fixed it last time.)

Comment: Aw snap! Policy editor exists only in editions Premium and above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your fix isn't practical when you need to do it again. There are many methods that should work but I think only one is really important. Take away the cause.

The trigger may very well be a misbehaving program start. The CPU does not have enough time left to complete the start of other processes in a decent way. This disables other icons most of the time but not always the same number. The network icon often has a red cross. Try to find the one notification tray program that can be bothering the others by guessing and watching the order. In my case a malware protector.

Go to properties in the context menu on the program icon and choose delayed start. I do not know the right translation in English or where exactly on which tab. Playing with these possibilities will let Windows wait triggering a delayed program until the moment the processor can be fully dedicated. Starting Windows should not take longer. Now wait using the computer only after this last icon has appeared. Just because the system keeps being occupied. May this icon problem ever return then choose more programs for delayed start. See how this works out.